Using Azure DataLakeServiceClient to download a file got forbidden response after few minutes success
I want to use Python to download file from OneLake, the file was uploaded within Power BI.
I have following code:
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

WORKSPACE_NAME = "workspace_2"
DATA_PATH = "DataflowsStagingLakehouse.Lakehouse/Files/logo.png"
account_url = f"https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com"

token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(WORKSPACE_NAME)
stream = file_system_client.get_file_client(DATA_PATH).download_file()
data = stream.readall()
with open("tmp.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)


I have created App registration in Azure portal named Eddie's App 2.
I have created Client secrets in Eddie's App 2.
I have setup environment variables AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET.
I have added Eddie's App 2 into my workspace as viewer.

I have successfully downloaded with the code & environment many times, but a few minutes later, it failed, I got following message:
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: User is not authorized to perform current operation for workspace 'some-uuid-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx' and artifact 'some-uuid-ooooooo-oooooo'
ErrorCode:Forbidden

I didn't change anything.
10:23:29 Success.
10:29:42 Success.
10:37:10 Fail.
Can someone help?
thx.


azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: The user is not authorized to perform the current operation for workspace 'some-uuid-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx' and artifact 'some-uuid-ooooooo-oooooo'. ErrorCode: Forbidden.

Initially, I received the same error when I added my service principal to my workspace as a viewer.
Error:

To download files from Azure OneLake, the service principal should have the Contributor role in the workspace.
Here are the steps to add the Contributor role to the workspace:
Portal:
Step 1:

Step 2:

After assigning the role to service principal, I ran the same code, and it executed successfully.
Code and Output:


Good, I'll try it for 1 day, if the problem was resolved, I'll mark correct answer, thank you.

sure, let know once checked
